# How to escape a variable in XL-Release

Tags: continuous-integration, nlog, xlrelease

Our XL-Release pipeline has placeholders with strings destined for an NLog config. NLog configs have syntax that support interpolated values using the same syntax as XL-Release uses for variables: `${variablename}`. For example, in NLog `${basedir}` equates to the base directory and `${shortdate}` gives a current timestamp string.

Unfortunately, XL-Release does a variable lookup on these values, finds nothing and replaces the intended NLog config text with nothing.

Is there a way to escape the NLog values so that XL-Release leaves them alone? Perhaps a backslash?: `\${variablename}`.

Fo example, our lookup dictionary has an entry like so:

```
"App": {
  "ProgramName": {
    "ArchiveFilename": "${basedir}/logs/archive/ProgramName-${shortdate}.log",
    "Filename": "${basedir}/logs/ProgramName.log"
  },
etc...
```

The template looks like this:

```
<targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="{{ App.ProgramName.Filename }}"
```

And, instead of getting this:

```
<targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/ProgramName.log"
```

I get this (XL-Release having dropped `${basedir}`):

```
<targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="/logs/ProgramName.log"
```

How can I escape `${basedir}` so XL-Release doesn't replace it?